# Getting Started with OpenDDS - Creating files that transfer data between devices

Tags: c++, idl, opendds, mpc

After reading the developer's guide listed on the OpenDDS website, I am still confused on how to set up my own project that allows the data types define to be transferred from the publisher to subscriber. The Messenger example provided in the documentation does not specify which files in the inventory were created as a result of building and which files were created by the developer. From what I currently understand, the DataType.idl, publisher.cpp, and subscriber.cpp have to be written by the developer and the rest of the files are created from the build system using ACE/TAO?

I have my datatypes all coded out in the idl file and am working on the publisher and subscriber but I do not know exactly what other files I need in order to build the project. I am thinking of using MPC since that is the more documented build system from their developer guide but can someone could help me determine what other files I need to set up as the developer?

Comment: If you have compiled and installed opendds on the machine you are working on and added the necessary libraries to the path, you do not need anything else for a basic structure. For a basic application, publisher.cc, subscriber.cc, data.idl and compilation files (makefile, MPC project file) are generally sufficient.